# Python: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I try to use pip to install sklearn, and I receive the following error message:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\jedi\\third_party\\django-stubs\\django-stubs\\contrib\\contenttypes\\management\\commands\\remove_stale_contenttypes.pyi'
```

I tried to install jupyter

Comment: @Chris - Why did you reject me edit?

Comment: I didn't. I improved it by removing the extraneous "thank you" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pip3 install sklearn`, or `pip install -U pip`

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the 260 character limit for file paths (about which python installer warned me at the end but I didn't pay enough attention to it :).
I followed https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/ to change it and then installed jupyter without an issue afterwards